# Creating new DataFrames from data between specific rows in main Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry if this has been asked anywhere else, but I wasn't sure how to describe this problem.

I have an example DataFrame like this:

```
import pandas as pd

s1 = {'Name' : ['BLOCK','A01','B02','BLOCK','BLOCK','C03','A01','BLOCK','BLOCK','B02','C03','A01','B02','C03','BLOCK'],
  'Value':  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],
  'ID': [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1]
  }

df = pd.DataFrame(s1)

df
     Name  Value  ID
0   BLOCK      1   1
1     A01      2   2
2     B02      3   1
3   BLOCK      4   2
4   BLOCK      5   1
5     C03      6   2
6     A01      7   1
7   BLOCK      8   2
8   BLOCK      9   1
9     B02     10   2
10    C03     11   1
11    A01     12   2
12    B02     13   1
13    C03     14   2
14  BLOCK     15   1
```

And I need to create new DataFrames based on the data in between the 'BLOCK' values of the first column. The resulting DataFrames should look like:

```
df1
   0    1  2
1  A01  2  2
2  B02  3  1

df2
   0    1  2
5  C03  6  2
6  A01  7  1

df3
    0    1   2
9   B02  10  2
10  C03  11  1
11  A01  12  2
12  B02  13  1
13  C03  14  2
```

It would be nice if I could do this for n number of potential DataFrames, but I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's create a dictionary of dataframes groupby by blocks:

```
m = df["Name"] != "BLOCK"
dict_dfs = dict(
    enumerate(
        [g for _, g in df[m].groupby((df["Name"] == "BLOCK").cumsum()[m])], start=1
    )
)

dict_dfs
```

Output:

```
{1:   Name  Value  ID
 1  A01      2   2
 2  B02      3   1,
 2:   Name  Value  ID
 5  C03      6   2
 6  A01      7   1,
 3:    Name  Value  ID
 9   B02     10   2
 10  C03     11   1
 11  A01     12   2
 12  B02     13   1
 13  C03     14   2}
```

Now, you can access your dataframes using

```
dict_dfs[1], dict_dfs[2] and dict_dfs[3]
```

Answer (score 1):

A more long-winded approach then the one suggested by Scott Boston but should work none the less.

First we obtain the indexes where `BLOCK` is the value. Then we create a sliding window from these pairs, excluding those that are less than length 2 and those that are two sequential `BLOCK`'s. Then we iterate over the valid pairs and index the DataFrame for those rows.

```
idxs = df.index[df["Name"] == "BLOCK"].tolist()
windows = [idxs[i: i + 2] for i in range(len(idxs))]

valid_windows = []
for window in windows:
    if len(window) < 2:
        continue
    x, y = window
    if x + 1 == y:
        continue
    valid_windows.append([x + 1, y])


for w in valid_windows:
    x, y = w
    print(df.iloc[x:y])

  Name  Value  ID
1  A01      2   2
2  B02      3   1
  Name  Value  ID
5  C03      6   2
6  A01      7   1
   Name  Value  ID
9   B02     10   2
10  C03     11   1
11  A01     12   2
12  B02     13   1
13  C03     14   2
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
import pandas as pd

s1 = {'Name' : ['BLOCK','A01','B02','BLOCK','BLOCK','C03','A01','BLOCK','BLOCK','B02','C03','A01','B02','C03','BLOCK'],
  'Value':  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],
  'ID': [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1]
  }

df = pd.DataFrame(s1)

x = pd.factorize(df['Name'].isin(['BLOCK']).iloc[::-1].cumsum().sort_index())[0]

df_list = list(list(df.groupby(x)))

dfs = []

for frame in df_list:
    df = frame[1]
    if (len(df)) > 1:
        df = df[:-1]
        dfs.append(df)
        
for df in dfs:
    print(df, '\n\n')
```

**Outputs:**

```
  Name  Value  ID
1  A01      2   2
2  B02      3   1 


  Name  Value  ID
5  C03      6   2
6  A01      7   1 


   Name  Value  ID
9   B02     10   2
10  C03     11   1
11  A01     12   2
12  B02     13   1
13  C03     14   2
```

Answer (score 0):

This works by getting the indices of each occurence of 'BLOCK'.

```py
import pandas as pd

s1 = {'Name' : ['BLOCK','A01','B02','BLOCK','BLOCK','C03','A01','BLOCK','BLOCK','B02','C03','A01','B02','C03','BLOCK'],
  'Value':  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],
  'ID': [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1]
  }

df = pd.DataFrame(s1)

idx = df.query('Name == "BLOCK"').index.tolist()

dfs = [df.iloc[idx[x]+1:idx[x+1],:] for x in  range(0,len(idx),2)]

for x in dfs:
  print(x)
```

```
Sample Output

  Name  Value  ID
1  A01      2   2
2  B02      3   1
  Name  Value  ID
5  C03      6   2
6  A01      7   1
   Name  Value  ID
9   B02     10   2
10  C03     11   1
11  A01     12   2
12  B02     13   1
13  C03     14   2
```